# Pandas groupby multiple columns exclusively

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the DataFrame below and want to find the count of `y` and `n` for each column:

| ID | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | y |  |
| 2 | n | y |
| 3 | y | n |
| 4 | y | n |
| 5 |  | y |

the result would be like this:

|  | var1_N | var2_N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| y | 3 | 2 |
| n | 1 | 2 |

I used `transform` function but was wondering there is a better way to get the results.
Thanks!

Comment: "I used `transform` function": Where is your current code?

Comment: not a clean solution for sure:

`cols = ["var1" , "var2"}
for var in cols:
    df1.groupby('var')['ID'].transform('count').unique()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do `value_counts` on all columns you need to count using `apply` method, the results will be automatically joined on the index (or var value in your case):

```
df.filter(like='var').apply(lambda s: s.value_counts())

   var1  var2
y     3     2
n     1     2
```

Or use `pd.value_counts` directly:

```
df.filter(like='var').apply(pd.value_counts)

   var1  var2
y     3     2
n     1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt` to flatten your dataframe then use `value_counts` and `unstack` the variable column:

```
>>> df.melt('ID').value_counts(['variable', 'value']).unstack('variable')

variable  var1  var2
value               
n            1     2
y            3     2
```

You can remove index and column names: by appending ``

Output:

```
>>> df.melt('ID').value_counts(['variable', 'value']).unstack('variable') \
      .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)

   var1  var2
n     1     2
y     3     2
```